# Electric Field due to Cubical Charge Distribution

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

What is the magnitude of electric field strength at the vertex of a uniformly charged cube of side 'a' and charge 'Q'?

Tried solving this by Gauss' law and by superposition but neither helped.

Comment: If there is only charge and no current then one of your questions should be easy. And if you used superposition you presumably integrated over all charges in the cube, which should be fine, so can you show us what you got and why you are not satisfied?

Comment: The same question was also asked two hours ago: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/808184 , so there may indeed be an assigned exercise to find the $E$-field at the vertex of a uniformly charged cube. (The correct answer, without revealing it, is somewhat complicated, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiqT1.png )