# Electric Flux through a cube by a charge situated at the vertex of it

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

I am asking this question because different websites are saying different things the different answers I am seeing are $\frac{Q}{8\epsilon_0}, \frac{Q}{24\epsilon_0}, \frac{Q}{6\epsilon_0}$. I am hearing different arguments for each one but I can't decide which is correct. The first one is simple and appealing. Previous PSE answers are saying the second option because flux depends on area or something. Can someone clarify with correct proof.

Comment: You need to clarify your post. Looking at "*different websites*" I have not found one which is about the *electric flux through the vertex of a cube* rather there are many sites related to a *charge situated at the vertex/corner of a cube*.

Comment: The same question was also asked two hours ago https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/808180 , so there may indeed be an assigned exercise to find the $E$-field at the vertex of a uniformly charged cube. (The correct answer, without revealing it, is more complicated, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiqT1.png )

Comment: *Previous PSE answers* Please provide links to them.

Comment: The flux “through a vertex” is zero since a vertex has no area. Do you understand the definition of flux?

Comment: @JosBergervoet That is not the same question as it is about a uniformly-charged cube.

Comment: This is a standard exercise question with a standard answer (use symmetry). As such, asking for the solution is off-topic.

Comment: To be honest I've never seen this exercise before and I was surprised to find that a short answer actually exists. (There is no clear symmetry to reduce the number of dimensions!) Maybe it does deserve to be treated again in e new question (later...)