Trouble understanding the experssion of gravity on a cube shaped earth
I'm a high school student working on a maths/geophysics project of which my goal is to try to mathmatically expressthe forces that apply on fluids, and then put them together to express geostrophic, gradient, and cyclostrophic winds on a cube shaped earth. I chose this topic because I know there have been some studies about gravity on a cube earth, so I thought this would be a fun way to expand the idea.
But I got stuck trying to understand this paper that mathematically expressed gravity on a cube earth. Could anybody explain how these equations were derived, and what they mean a bit more specifically?
Also I would like to know if there are any tips on how I should approach this project.

That's a really ambitious project! If you have experience with using calculus to compute the electric potential from, say, a ring of charge, then the equations you've highlighted are computed in a very similar way (but obviously the integrals are much more complicated!). You are basically computing the gravitational potential $dV=GdM/r$ from each mass element on the cube, and then integrating (summing) those together, $V=\int dV$. If you don't have experience doing that, you might want to try simplifying the project into something more manageable.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130789/123208 which links to that Chappell (2012) paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3857

There was an interesting similar question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/808180/electric-field-due-to-cubical-charge-distribution but unfortunately the question was closed and seems to be deleted (I really don't know why, closing of questions follows strange rules...)

Do you understand calculus? Do you understand gravitational potential? Do you understand superposition?
